# Wrong array order after populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the problem but I can't paste whole code here so let me try to explain. I need to find some document by id and populate its ObjectId's element of array. Let's say I have following document from User collection:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  "first_name":"Nick",
  "last_name":"Parsons",
  "email":"nick@movementstrategy.com",
  "password":"foo",
  "clients":[
    "50f5e901545cf990c500000f",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000010",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000013"
  ]
}
```

After finding it I'm populate its clients like this:

```
User.findById(1)
  .populate('clients')
  .exec(function (err, user) {

  });
```

After the code above is executed I have 'user' variable with populated array of clients. But the clients have the wrong order, something like this:

```
       {
          _id: "50f5e901545cf990c500000f",
          "first_name":"cl1",
       },
       {
          _id: "50f5e90b545cf990c5000013",
          "first_name":"cl3",
       },
       {
          _id: "50f5e90b545cf990c5000010",
          "first_name":"cl2",
       }
```

Should be:

```
    "50f5e901545cf990c500000f",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000010",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000013"
```

Instead of:

```
    "50f5e901545cf990c500000f",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000013",
    "50f5e90b545cf990c5000010"
```

Does anybody has the similar problem or am I lucky?

**EDIT:** I've added the code: http://pastie.org/5901177
In that code I create 3 clients and pushed into user.clients array. After that I added one more client on a top of user.clients array. So when I do

```
  Client.where('_id').in(user.clients)
```

I'm getting wrong order. Look at this please via console.

Comment: Well, without the code there's really not much we can do. Simplify your code into a small runnable snippet that still reproduces the problem. Often in the process of doing that you find the problem cause.

Comment: Can you provide a template of runnable snippet?

Comment: sure, here you go: http://pastie.org/5896052. You can save it as a .js file and run

Comment: added the code. Please look at

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, every modification (or added document) goes to the bottom of the list. If you want your items to be returned in a specific order, specify that in the query:

```
User.find()
    .sort({_id: 1})
```

where `-1` specifies the reverse order. You can sort by any other criterion.

Comment: But it's Array so order is determined by its elements.